# Sitting During Laining accd to R Abadi

Tags: torah-reading, standing-sitting

I have seen that Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi is careful that all present at his Shul **must sit** during Torah reading.

Why is that?

Comment: I assume that you mean R' Abadi says the congregants should sit, but that the person reading the Torah (and the Gabbai and Gabbai Sheni) must stand ([*Shulchan Aruch* OC 141:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90), Rama ad loc., [*M.B.* 141:5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90)).

Answer (score 10):

Because the Halacha is that you can sit (and such was the custom in the majority of synagogues in the period of the Rishonim), and everyone in a given place should follow the same custom. ([Or Yitzchak 1:53](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=57&hilite=))

Comment: Everyone in a given synagogue should follow the same custom--wheres the mekor?

Comment: See the end of the Teshuva. BM 86b. Moshe ate bread his whole life, but when he went to heaven for 40 days, he followed the custom of the angels to not eat bread.

Comment: So that means that if I go to a Yeshiva where everyone stands I must do that as well?

Comment: @Moshe So it would seem, accd to R Abadi.

Comment: @Double I would argue that even in a Yeshiva the standing is not done as halacha, rather as a chumra, as opposed to a kehila which sits which is acting according to their opinion of the halacha is. Even the minhag about eating can be argued to be more binding than a chumra.

Comment: @user6591 **חומרות** מקום שבאו לשם If everyone's doing it then that's seemingly the custom.

Comment: +1. Note that there are many views among recent poskim on the matter of whether it is praiseworthy (but not required), optional (essentially to the point of being neutral), or bad to stand in a congregation where people generally sit for the reading. The issues involved are generally *yuhara* and *minhag hamakom* (and whether they apply) vs. showing reverence for the Torah by standing (reminiscent of Har Sinai). Factors that could affect this, according to at least some poskim, include whether the rav of the synagogue stands and the percentage of the congregation that does stand.

Answer (score 1):

The opinion of the Vilna Gaon (Biur HaGr"a קמו-ט) (and pre-Maharam M'rottenberg who was first to be mechadesh this idea- as I heard from Rav Herschel Shachter that even in the shul of the Maharam nobody stood for Krias Hatorah, as this was the predominent minhag) was to sit during Krias Hatorah.

Al pi Kabbala according to the Arizal one SHOULD sit for Krias HaTorah.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21913/discussion-on-answer-by-mefaresh-sitting-during-laining-accd-to-r-abadi).