# Standing for the last aliyah of a sefer

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, standing-sitting

Right before the final aliyah today (Parshat Pekudei) the gabbai asked everyone to stand up. He does this before the final aliyah of each of the books of the Torah. While I have seen discussions about standing during leining in general, or standing for the 10 hadibrot, I can't find any source or (more importantly) reason for one to stand specifically for the last aliyah of the sefer.

**as per comments**: apparently in some places, the people are asked to stand (via a klopp or something else) just for the last pasuk. Asking before the aliyah would avoid an interruption at that point.

Why is this aliyah (or this pasuk) different from other aliyot in that people are asked to stand?

Comment: This is a new one for me. It was the entire aliyah and not just the last verse?

Comment: I've seen the Gabbai Klop before the last verse and people rise then. Seemingly standing for the whole Aliyah is to avoid interruption during the Aliyah and/or to avoid the impression that certain verses are more important than others. (Why stand for the last pasuk though is still unclear.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43361 & http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6170

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13331/759

Comment: shouldn't we stand for all of leining?

Comment: @Dude there is much written about this. Start with http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.com/2014/01/please-remain-seated-sitting-during.html and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56243/sitting-during-laining-accd-to-r-abadi

Answer (score 1):

R. Shmuel Pinhas Gelbard writes [here](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=85966) that the reason is simply to be standing for the upcoming kaddish:

> הטעם שעומדים, משום שבאשכנז המנהג לעמוד באמירת הש"ץ קדיש, ואחרי "חזק" בעל הקורא או הש"ץ אומר קדיש

Comment: Wouldn't this apply to the last Aliyah every week? What am I missing?

Comment: I wondered the same thing. Perhaps he means that the minhag evolved from people standing for kaddish and others mistaking this for standing for 'hazak'.

Comment: R' Gelbard, there, says that the source for saying חזק חזק ונתחזק is [רמ"א או"ח סי' קל"ט סעיף יא](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.139.11?lang=bi), which says (echoing [Beit Yosef there](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef,_Orach_Chaim.139.11?lang=bi) that the minhag is to say חזק after - it looks to me - *every aliya*. That would fit well with standing for the impending *Kadish* (at least, when the *aliya* is the last of the day). The question R' Gelbard seems to skip is why Ashkenazim *only* say חזק at the end of a *sefer*.